# Parted Resize doesnt show up in mount

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos, gparted

I used GParted to resize/move a partition on disk. The initial size was 50MB, but I shrunk my C:\ partition in windows, and then moved the start back 50GB

This shows up in parted

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MK5061GS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  41.1MB  41.1MB  primary   fat16             
 2      41.9MB  830MB   789MB   primary   ntfs         boot 
 3      830MB   394GB   393GB   primary   ntfs              
 4      394GB   500GB   106GB   extended                    
 5      446GB   447GB   107MB   logical   ext3              
 6      447GB   500GB   53.6GB  logical                lvm
```

So you can see that there is no gap between 3 and 4 here, which there would have been if I hadnt moved the partition, and expanded it from 50GB to 100GB.

however, when I do df -h

The logical volume still shows as 50GB (well, 40GB + 10GB swap), so I am not able to use that space.

```
Filesystem             Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                        42G    28G    13G  69% /
/dev/sda5              104M    28M    72M  28% /boot
tmpfs                  4.2G      0   4.2G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1              985G    22G   913G   3% /media/disk
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enlarged /dev/sda6, you need to resize the volume group on it afterwards, for LVM to make use of it:

> pvresize /dev/sda6

Just run it as root, no need to unmount anything, etc.

After that, you need to resize the logical volume, if you want your root filesystem to take all that new free space:

> lvresize --resizefs -l +100%PVS /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00

You can tweak `-l` parameter to specify how much you want your volume to grow, e.g. `-l +10G` will enlarge it 10GB.

Thanks to `--resizefs` parameter, the filesystem on this volume will be resized automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
partprobe
```

You may need to run this command on a live system for the kernel to see the changes.